# Why would Safari passwords not be in Keychain?

Tags: macos, safari, keychain

My friend’s Mac has been saving Safari passwords for the past 4 years. But somehow they are all gone now. I tried looking in his keychain and they aren’t in there.

Is this a case where — for some reason — there is a bug or problem in macOS has deleted them?

Comment: I've never known keychain just 'lose' passwords. I have some going back to 2009 that have been migrated from Mac to Mac down the years. Perhaps double-check they're also missing from Safari's passwords pref pane.

Comment: Yeah they are gone in the safari pref pane too.

Comment: Grab a good one back from Time Machine. I wouldn't trust the rest if one part has corrupted.

Comment: I tried a keychain-db from various dates in Time Machine and extracted with Chainbreaker2, no luck that the safari passwords are in those files.

Comment: The only conclusion I can draw is that someone has intentionally purged them.